# Restarting FormWizard from done method

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I'm trying use the FormWizard for to submit an order "charge" in wizard `done` method. Extending the example in the documentation, performing the credit card "charge" in the `done` means you can't go back and reprompt for credit card, because the wizard performs `self.storage.reset()` *after* calling the `done` method.

What is the right approach? The confirmation form `clean()` step is called multiple times for revalidation, etc, & seems too removed from `done()` where all validated forms are available.

Thanks for any pointers.

Kent

Comment: Just so I understand the question and for simplicity, lets say you have three forms. On form two, you are collecting credit card information. After the user submits form two, you are wanting to check with your payment processor to make sure what the user supplied is valid, and if not, redisplay form two with the errors. If successful display form three?

Comment: The problem is even if the payment info is "valid", the amount can still be "declined". I would like create order model instance & charge when passed all validated forms in `done`. But in `done` can't go back to `revalidate_form`. Just doesn't seem to be a good way to handle errors in `do something with the data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is "you can't get there from here". I opened a ticket #19189, but it's unclear this feature will be added.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of this:

- In `done()` method you will be charging the user. If its declined/failed, save each forms data in session/cookies.
- Restart the wizard from specific step where payment info is taken. [NamedUrlWizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#usage-of-namedurlwizardview) might be helpful.
- Implement your [`get_form_intial()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form_initial) to return data from session/cookies for the step.

However, I think validation of this may fail as skipped steps do not have data. So you may have to do some more to get pass that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
1. extend WizardView, modify render_done method to catch exception in it:
 - [detailed description](http://vasylok.blogspot.com/2014/10/restarting-django-sessionwizard-from.html)

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class MySessionWizardView(SessionWizardView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MySessionWizardView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.has_errors = False

    class RevalidationError(Exception):
        def __init__(self, step, form, **kwargs):
            self.step = step
            self.form = form
            self.kwargs = kwargs

        def __repr__(self):
            return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__, self.step)
        __str__ = __repr__

    def render_done(self, form, **kwargs):
        final_form_list = []
        for form_key in self.get_form_list():
            form_obj = self.get_form(step=form_key,
                data=self.storage.get_step_data(form_key),
                files=self.storage.get_step_files(form_key))
            if not form_obj.is_valid():
                return self.render_revalidation_failure(form_key, form_obj, **kwargs)
            final_form_list.append(form_obj)

        try:
            done_response = super(MySessionWizardView, self).render_done(form, **kwargs)
        except self.RevalidationError as e:
            return self.render_revalidation_failure(e.step, e.form, **e.kwargs)
        self.storage.reset()
        return done_response
```